# Numbering sequence number in DataGrid ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I tried to mark numbering in `DataGrid` ASP.NET control but unsuccessfully. Some guys show me the link that look like working but it does not work for me. Please help - `DataGrid` not `GridView` or `DataList`.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="tdCenter">
        <HeaderTemplate> No.</HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:ItemTemplate>   
           <%# (grdAttDetails.PageSize * grdAttDetails.CurrentPageIndex)   + Container.ItemIndex + 1%> 
         </asp:ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="RowCount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# (DataGrid1.PageSize * DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex) + Container.ItemIndex + 1%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

PageIndexChanged Event:

```
        protected void DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            DataGrid1.DataBind();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Result with paging:

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: :This works for me  but only first page with Paging allow = true , we have so many pages,the next page reset to number 1 ..... Help!

Comment: i edited the markup and added PageIndexChanged event handler, take a look.

Comment: posted results with paging.

Answer (score 1):

**Generate Sequence Number in Datagrid from SQL:**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS SeqNumber FROM TABLE_NAME
```

AND Bind DataGrid as,

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SeqNumber")%>
```

just try it and please let me know weather it works or not..