# Container.DisplayIndex not working with paging in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, pagination

I have a gridview that is bound with data from code behind. Paging is applied in gridview. Everything works fine. For showing **Row-Index** i use `Container.DisplayIndex`.

When i go to next page through paging, every time gridview bind perfectly but DisplayIndex start with 1 to pagesize. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

**Here is Asp.NET Code:**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="dlAddress" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="dlAddress_PageIndexChanging" >
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code:**

```
public void bindGridView()
{
        DBACon.Open();
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("getAddresses", DBACon);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter AHadp = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
        AHadp.Fill(DS);
        dlAddress.DataSource = DS;
        dlAddress.DataBind();
}

protected void dlAddress_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
       dlAddress.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       bindGridView();
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question for a `DataGrid`. Take a look and see if it helps. You would just need to change the index naming, i guess. [Sequence Numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628482/numbering-sequence-number-in-datagrid-asp-net/31629134#31629134)

Comment: Basically you need to account for page size and current index in your binding.

Comment: when i am on 1st page then it show 1 to 10 after that 11 to 20 and so on but currently every page it shows 1 to 10

Comment: It sounds it is doing what you want, so I don't understand what you mean by _...but currently every page shows 1 to 10..._ .  The problem i see is that you're using only the current index in your current binding, when you should be also using page size as shown in my answer. Did you look at the link i posted?

Comment: every page it shows 1 to 10 that's not good. i want to show 1 to 10 then 11 to 20 then 21 to 30 so on.

Comment: Ok, i understand that. Did you look at the link i sent you?

Comment: yes but `CurrentPageIndex` is not working with gridview

Comment: In `GridView` it is called `PageIndex`... `CurrentPageIndex` is for `DataGrid`, you just need to do the mapping but the idea is the same.

Comment: This is what i believe the expression for your label should look like: `<%# (dlAddress.PageSize * dlAddress.PageIndex) + Container.DisplayIndex + 1%>`.

Comment: Please try it and let me know. I can't try it on my own because my SQL server is down right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

ASPX:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AddressID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RowNumber">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# (GridView1.PageSize * GridView1.PageIndex) + Container.DisplayIndex + 1%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]